# Asymptotic Freedom and the Continuum Limit

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

Suppose I have a family of effective field theories, parametrized by a cut-off $\Lambda$ and a coupling constant $g$ and specified in terms of generating functionals $Z_{\Lambda,g}(J)$. Asymptotic freedom means that there is a renormalized trajectory $g(\Lambda)$ such that $\lim\limits_{\Lambda\to\infty} g(\Lambda) = 0$ and $Z_{\Lambda,g(\Lambda)}(J)$ is a sequence of effective field theories emanating from the renormalization group fixed point.

I should be able to take the limit
$$Z^*(J):=\lim\limits_{\Lambda\to\infty} Z_{\Lambda,g(\Lambda)}$$
to obtain the continuum limit of these effective theories. Now it appears to me that $Z^*(J)$ should be a free theory, since it should correspond the fixed point of the renormalization group where $g=0$. So the UV completion of an asymptotically free theory appears to be a free theory.

Something must be wrong with this reasoning. Please explain!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The critical point is determined by the location of the fixed point and the critical exponent at that point. For example, if the theory is asymptotically free with only one coupling constant, we can say that the UV fixed point of the theory lies on a line satisfying $g=0$, but nothing more. Of course, the free field is always a candidate for a fixed point on this line.

So, if after taking the limit of $\Lambda\to\infty$, the theory goes to the obvious fixed point, then your claim is correct, but in fact there are multiple counterexamples.

For example, let’s consider the $O(N)$ non-linear sigma model on 2-dimensional space time.

This is known as an asymptotic free theory. That theory has one coupling constant $g$, and it approaches to zero at UV:  $\ g(\Lambda)\overset{\Lambda\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$

However, this theory does not approach to the free theory at UV. To see this let’s consider the 2-point function $G(r;g)$. It is known that the 2-point function of this theory show the logarithmic behavior:
$$G(r;g)\sim (\log r)^{2\gamma},$$
where $\gamma$ is a critical exponent and it is nonzero and not one, so this theory is not a free theory.

In summary, to examine the behavior at UV, the condition that the coupling constant tends to zero is not enough, we need more information about the UV **fixed point**. If the UV fixed point is an obvious fixed point, then your argument is correct. However, there are known counterexamples such as nonlinear sigma model above and 4-dimensional YM theory, so fortunately we can construct interesting examples.

More details can be found for example in the lecture note written by Fradkin: [The perturbative renormalization group](http://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys583/RG-ch16.pdf).